# What's the difference between "net" and "netting"?

Tags: differences

I recently heard the word "netting" in a conversation with an Englishman. Then looked it up to figure out what makes it different to "net". These are the two definitions I got from the Oxford dictionary:

**netting:** material that is made of string, thread or wire twisted or tied together, with spaces in between

**net:** a type of material that is made of string, thread or wire twisted or tied together, with small spaces in between

A search on the internet didn't help much. What is the difference (if any) between these two words?

Comment: You can cast the net. You can't cast the netting.

Comment: I would suggest that a *net* is a device e.g. *fishing net*, *hairnet* etc. which is usually made from a type of material which might be called *netting*.

Comment: A net is made of netting.

Comment: Not sure where you got those definitions, but they aren't what my Oxford says. "net: a type of material …" is very misleading. A net is not a "type" of material at all: it's an object characteristic of a particular configuration of material, so to speak. A net is a specific kind of object, while netting any kind of intertwined materials that form a kind of net-like structure.

Comment: Here are my sources: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/net_2 and http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/netting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this crude picture I whipped up:

[image]

The material making the red part is probably some form of rigid metal wire, or maybe a modern composite.  The material in the blue part could be wood, metal, plastic, or again a composite.  The *material* in the black part can be called either net or netting.

The *entire device* is called a net.  Specifically, this drawing depicts a butterfly net.  If anyone called it a butterfly netting, I would think it very strange.

In your own sources, notice that "netting" has only one definition, beginning with "material" whereas "net" has multiple definitions- this first refers to material again, but the second talks about the "piece" put to a specific purpose.  Here is another [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/netting) giving very similar results.

Similarly, wikipedia has seperate pages for [net (device)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(device)) and [net (textile)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(textile)) where only the latter mentions it can also be called netting.

<sub>Note: I have assumed you only care about the use of the two words as nouns.  As verbs, then of course "netting" is the participle of "to net."</sub>

Comment: You could also compare this to *mosquito netting*, which is a fine mesh material designed to block out mosquitoes. The use of *netting* describes the material itself. If you were to refer to a *mosquito net*, you'd be talking about some apparatus to hang the netting around a bed or some such.